# What happens to Isolation Level in Stored Proc that fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SP that takes about 30 seconds to run.  10 seconds of this creating an initial temp table on which I operate eg.

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM view_name ....(lots of joins and where conditions)
```

My understanding is that by default this long select (insert) can lock the table and therefore the application attached to the database?

My solution to this was to add

```
SET ISOLATION TRANSACTION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

to the top of the Stored Proc and then reset it to COMMITED at the end.

I guess this is a two part question firstly is my understanding of this correct and secondly if somewhere in my SP it fails with an error.   Will the DB remain in UNCOMMITTED mode?

Comment: Which table are you referring to when you say it can `lock the table`?

Comment: Basically all the tables that are involved in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case of code executed from a stored procedure, the isolation level is reset to what it was before you called the stored procedure, regardless of what happens. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql):

> If you issue `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked.

If you're not using a stored procedure, or you're dealing with code *inside* the stored procedure, the (much more complicated) story follows below.

---

Isolation level is a property of the *session*, not of the *database*. Whether or not a statement like `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` executes after an error depends on whether the error aborts the entire batch or only the statement. The rules for this are [complicated and unintuitive](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification). To make things even more interesting, the isolation level of a session is [not reset if it's associated with a pooled connection](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level). If you want foolproof code that maintains an isolation level, preferably set the isolation level consistently from client code. If you must do it in T-SQL, it's a good idea to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and `TRY .. CATCH`, or the `WITH (NOLOCK)` table hint to restrict the locking options to a particular table or tables.

But why complicate your life? Consider if you *really* need to use `READ UNCOMMITTED` (or `WITH (NOLOCK)`), because [you have no guarantee of data consistency anymore when you do](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2009/04/10/how-dirty-are-your-reads.aspx), and even if you *think* you're OK with that, it can lead to results that aren't just a little bit wrong but completely useless. Unfortunately, this is true especially when the load on the database increases (which is why you might consider reducing locking in the first place).

If your query takes a long time while locking data, *and* that is a problem to applications (neither of which should be *assumed*, because SQL Server is good at locking data for only as long as necessary), your first instinct should be to see if the query itself can be optimized to reduce lock time (by adding indexes, most likely). If you've still got unacceptable locking left, consider using [snapshot isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tcbchxcb). Only after those things have been evaluated should you consider dirty reads, and even then only for cases where consistency of the data is not your primary concern (for example, the query gets some monitoring statistics that are refreshed every so often anyway).

Comment: @GlenHong: most of my answer is invalidated by the fact that I missed that you're using a stored procedure. Within a stored procedure, it's much easier to get away with this because the isolation level is reset. I changed the answer to include that.